# python reemplace string in contents of files and in the files names in the current folder

Tags: python

i'm using this script to reemplace string in filenames and contents of files on a current folder:

https://gist.github.com/meddulla/1262462

content:

```
"""
Usage: python script.py search_string replace_string dir
Eg. python batchreplace.py galleries productions /Sites/cjc/application/modules/productions/
And it will search recursively in dir
and replace search_string in contents
and in filenames.
Case-sensitive
"""

from sys import argv
import os

def multi_replace(search, replace, path):
    """Replace search with replace in all filenames
    and file contents in directory path.
    @type   search: string
    @param  search: The old string.
    @type   replace: string
    @param  replace: The new string.
    @type   path: string
    @param  path: The path in which files area.
    @rtype: boolean
    @returns: True or False. Also print a msg to the console.
    """
    counter_contents = 0
    counter_names = 0
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        print 'Path does not exist'
        return False
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            # replace contents
            indata = open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)).read()
            if search in indata:
                new = indata.replace(search, replace)
                output = open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), "w")
                output.write(new)
                counter_contents +=1

            # replace in filename
            if search in filename:
                os.rename(
                    os.path.join(dirpath, filename),
                    os.path.join(dirpath, filename.replace(search, replace))
                )
                counter_names +=1

    print '%s files renamed, %s files contents altered' % (counter_names,counter_contents)
    return True

script, search_str, replace_str, path_str = argv

multi_replace(search_str, replace_str, path_str)
```

When I run this code with:

```
phython replacer.py customer clients ./
```

I get this error:

-bash: phython: command not found

I'm using Python 2.7.12 on a Mac. It looks I don't need upgrade to python 3, becase the script was wrriten 6 years ago.

I'm not expert in phyton so i don't realize the error

Comment: try with `python ...`

Comment: you are right, i'm going to try, looks PATH environment does not work to find the python file.. need to go to the folder where script python is.

Comment: nice, it's working